SPSS Mixed: Save and plot estimated random effects
I would like to plot estimated random effects obtained from an SPSS mixed model. I use the following syntax as an MWE:
   MIXED Y WITH X1 X2 
    /PRINT = SOLUTION TESTCOV G
    /METHOD = ML 
    /FIXED = INTERCEPT X1 X2
    /RANDOM = Intercept X1| SUBJECT(ID) SOLUTION
    /SAVE PRED(Pre_1) RESID(Res_1). 

I am able to make SPSS print the estimates of random intercept and random slope (via the SOLUTION option in the \RANDOM statement), but I but I cannot find a way to save these estimates as variables so that I can plot them. Am I overlooking something?
If there is a solution, it would be great if it is simple enough to work with by undergraduate students who are working with SPSS syntax for the first time.
